# Sufficient statistic for the family of PERT distributions?

Tags: beta-distribution, sufficient-statistics

A **beta distribution** is one of the form
$$
\text{constant}\times x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \, dx \quad \text{ for } 0<x<1.
$$

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERT_distribution) Wikipedia article, the family of "PERT distributions" is that of **rescaled** and **relocated** beta distributions with $$\alpha+\beta=6,$$ conventionally parametrized by the endpoints $a<c$ of the interval of support, and the mode $b.$

Thus the distribution is
$$
\text{constant} \times (x-a)^{\alpha-1} (c-x)^{\beta-1} \quad \text{for } a<x<c 
$$
where
\begin{align}
\alpha & = 1 + 4\cdot\frac{b-a}{c-a}, \\[8pt]
\beta & = 1 + 4\cdot\frac{c-b}{c-a}.
\end{align}

What is the minimal sufficient statistic for this family of distributions? (This will not depend on which parametrization is used.)